# Getting error while trying to login to skype 4.3 in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS?

Tags: skype

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on my machine since long. i upgrade the skype from 4.2 to 4.3 and successfully installed after that when i login to skype able to successfully login to skype but skype window flash out from the my screen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm on Kubuntu 14.04, but faced the same problem. Fixed it like this:

`$apt-get update ; apt-get install sqlite`

`$sqlite3 ~/.Skype/[username]/main.db`

Inside, copy/paste this (and press enter):

`UPDATE messages
   SET body_xml =(
         SELECT SUBSTR( body_xml, files_start, alt_end - files_start ) ||
                SUBSTR( body_xml, 0, files_start ) ||
                SUBSTR( body_xml, alt_end )
           FROM (
             SELECT msg.body_xml,
                    instr( msg.body_xml, '<files' )  files_start,
                    instr( msg.body_xml, 'alt="' ) + 5 alt_end
               FROM messages msg
              WHERE msg.id = messages.id
           )
       )
 WHERE type = 68
   AND body_xml NOT LIKE '<file%';`

To quit, enter:

`.quit`

This saved all of my history!

Sources:

http://community.skype.com/t5/Linux/Skype-4-3-crash-on-ubuntu-14-04/td-p/3219892/page/3

Comment: i think it might be okay but i did i was removed all things from ~/.Skype/ folder and reinstall the skype and login i able to login

Comment: +1 This is absolutely the best solution in order to save Skype history when upgrading from Skype 4.2 to 4.3. I also searched the net for quite a bit. Other people suggested SQLite queries such as `UPDATE Messages SET body_xml=substr(body_xml,instr(body_xml,'<files')) WHERE type=68 AND body_xml LIKE 'posted%';`, which works but is not quite as good since (1) it only works on english installations ([though it can be translated](http://community.skype.com/t5/Linux/Skype-4-3-crashes-with-old-chat-history/m-p/3226998#M9273)) and (2) loses the tiniest bit of information in the file transfer history.